# I have a Input which auto fills its data using the value of other Input field but i donot want to fill it automatically

Tags: angular

I have a Input which auto fills its data using the value of other Input field but i donot want to fill it automatically and i want to enter the value manuallyenter code here
How to do this

based on value of "INPUT:CNAPS CODE" the other INPUT "BANK NAME value is filled
but i do not want to auto fill it i want to enter it manually

```
<div class="col-md-6 inputSingleAdjustment" *ngIf="item.bankCountryCode !=''">
<label>{{ item.routingLabel || 'Bank Code ' }}--->CNAPS CODE
<i class="validateField" *ngIf="item.routingLabel != 'SWIFT'">*</i>
 <span class="maskTextInput"> {{ item.routingInputMask }}</span>
                </label>
                <!-- [disabled]="item.disableBankABARouting" -->
                <input
                  type="text"
                  oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"
                  [(ngModel)]="item.abaRouting"
                  class="form-control text-uppercase  ng-invalid ng-invalid-required sp-focus"
                  (blur)="item.routingBlur = true; checkClabeOriginal(item)"
                  (focus)="item.routingBlur = false; validateMexico(item)"
                  required=""
                  autofocus=""
                  #routingNum="ngModel"
                  name="abaRouting"
                  (change)="prepareSwifts(item); !routingNum.errors ? validateRoutingNumber(item) : ''"
                  [ngClass]="{
                    invalid:
                      (submitted && (routingNum.errors?.pattern || routingNum.errors?.required)) ||
                      (routingNum.errors?.pattern && item.routingBlur == true)
                  }"
                  [pattern]="item.routingRegEx"
                  placeholder=""
                  [ngbTooltip]="abaTooltip"
                  placement="bottom"
                  (ngModelChange)="toAbaRoutingUppercase(item)"
                />



 <div class="col-md-6 inputSingleAdjustment tooltip-custom-class" *ngIf="!item.chinaCase">
                    <label
                      >Bank Name:
                      <i class="validateField" [hidden]="!item.bankNameDisabled">*</i>
                    </label>'
                    <input
                      ngbTooltip="Please provide institution name"
                      strip-spaces
                      placement="right"
                      type="text"
                      #institutionName="ngModel"
                      class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required"
                      [(ngModel)]="item.institution_name"
                      [disabled]="item.bankNameDisabled"
                      [required]="item.bankNameDisabled"
                      autofocus=""
                      placeholder=""
                      name="institutionName"
                      [ngClass]="{ invalid: submitted && institutionName?.errors?.required }"
                      bankNameDisabled
                    />
                  </div>`
```

Comment: You need to also show the `<input>` tag for `CNAPS CODE`.

Comment: ok i will add that code

Comment: MODIFIED MY POST @MichaelD